# why react-native link only link ios cant link android

Tags: react-native, hyperlink

when i run react-native link,it just link ios,can not link android.
,and i already manually link andoird,it cant work

[image]
 manually link andoird

> react-native link react-native-device-info

Platform 'ios' module react-native-device-info is already linked

Comment: `link` command in react-native cli 1.x is buggy and it's generally recommended to link native modules manually.